# FORALL SELECT getting NO DATA FOUND

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulk

Similar to a question posted ([PL/SQL No Data found error on forall loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530659/pl-sql-no-data-found-error-on-forall-loop)),
I recently just found out that i can use `FORALL` with `SELECT`. so i tried the below code in a PL/SQL block:

```
FORALL i in p_eit_hdr_rec.first..p_eit_hdr_rec.last
select  count(*)
into    l_exists
from    TABLE_X x1
    ,   TABLE_Y x2
    ,   TABLE_Z x3
where   x2.batch_name = p_eit_hdr_rec(i).batch_name
and     x1.person_id  = x2.person_id
and     x2.status     = 'New'
and     x3.information_type = x1.information_type
and     x3.EIT_INT_HDR_ID   = x2.EIT_INT_HDR_ID;
```

Where `p_eit_hdr_rec` is an Associative Array, `p_eit_hdr_rec(i).batch_name` contains the string 'hire_20170711_200005.csv' and `l_exists` is a NUMBER variable defaulted to `0`.
I get the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception even if i confirmed that there is data being fetched when i query it as a normal SQL:

```
select  count(*)
into    l_exists
from    TABLE_X x1
    ,   TABLE_Y x2
    ,   TABLE_Z x3
where   x2.batch_name = 'hire_20170711_200005.csv'
and     x1.person_id  = x2.person_id
and     x2.status     = 'New'
and     x3.information_type = x1.information_type
and     x3.EIT_INT_HDR_ID   = x2.EIT_INT_HDR_ID;

COUNT(*)
--------
2
```

Why am i Gettting the Exception? Is `FORALL SELECT` a valid syntax but not valid for checking data?

Comment: Is it possible that `p_eit_hdr_rec` has gaps? `p_eit_hdr_rec(i)` would give a NDF exception if it had no element `i`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson by Gaps, do you mean there might be null values inside `p_eit_hdr_rec`?

Comment: No, I mean the case where `p_eit_hdr_rec.first` is 1 and `p_eit_hdr_rec.last` is 3 and there is no 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I recently just found out that i can use `FORALL` with `SELECT`.

No, you can't.

Reading the fine [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm) about [FORALL Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321):

> ***dml_statement***
>
> A static or dynamic INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement that references at least one collection in its VALUES or WHERE clause. Performance benefits apply only to collection references that use index as an index.

So, one can't use `forall` with `select`. The corresponding [bulk SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS01205) operation for `select` is [SELECT INTO Statement with BULK COLLECT Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#GUID-6E09E4FC-28C0-43C8-9E7C-A54D6398D1DE).

Happy reading !

Answer (score 1):

FOR ALL statement is usually used for doing DML statements like INSERT UPDATE DELETE.That is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: Just use the FOR statement instead of FOR ALL

Comment: Just use the FOR statement instead of FOR ALL.FOR ALL is used usually for BULK DML operations for INSERT UPDATE and DELETE

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments, here is an example of how to use FORALL with BULK COLLECT:

```
declare 
  TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF TABLE1%ROWTYPE;
  obj_data ARRAY;
  i integer;
  CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
begin
  OPEN c1;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO obj_data limit 32768;

      FORALL i IN 1..obj_data.COUNT
        INSERT /*+ append */ INTO TABLE2 
          VALUES obj_data(i);

      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;      
    END LOOP;
    commit;
  CLOSE c1;
end;
/
```

Comment: I was hoping the answer would be in line with the `FORALL` being used in a `SELECT` statement inside a PL/SQL block.

Comment: [`append_values`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABFIHGA), surely?

Answer (score 0):

Avery simple explaination would be that your Associative array may contain list of elements and not a sinlge element. Now you have tried to query out the SQL statement with only one element.

And secondly `FORALL SELECT` as mentioned above is not possible. You need to Iterate through each record and then find the count. That will be the alternative i would suggest.